# Why the storing on this sequence of numbers is skipped?

Tags: c, arrays, scanf, stdio

[real code cases](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tnc8o.jpg)

```
#include <stdio.h>    
int main()
{
    char names[10][50];
    int i, j, N;
    scanf("%d",&N);
    int dnaSeq[N][20];
    for(i=0;i<N;i++)
    {
        printf("asking for a name: ");
        scanf("%50[^\n]s",&names[i]);

        for(j=0;j<20;j++)
            scanf("%d",&dnaSeq[i][j]);
    }
}
```

For some reason the second "for" is skipped when running this.
I'm trying to input first some names that include whitespaces and also have a maximum of 50 characters, but I have no problem whatsoever when I'm trying to run this code without those specifications (just scanf("%s",&names[i]);).
Any idea why this happens?

I already tried with gets and fget.

Comment: `scanf("%50[^\n]s",&names[i]);` --> `scanf(" %49[^\n]",&names[i]);`  (add space, 49, drop s)

Comment: "Why the storing on this sequence of numbers is skipped?" the first thing to do is to recode and check the return value of `scanf()` to see it is as expected.